# Using com.google.android.vending (Android APK expansion files) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I'm trying to use Android APK expansion files in my Android Studio project. I've followed the instructions available in the official site: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Preparing

In Android Studio I have these 2 modules:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa9zi.png)

build.gradle file of one of the modules (the other one is similar):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}

repositories {
    "/Users/andro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/play_licensing"
}
```

In the build.gradle file of the main project I have this dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile project(':viewpagerindicator')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile project(':googleplaylicenselibrary')
compile project(':playdownloaderlibrary')
}
```

But I still get this error when trying to use anything from the Downloader service:

```
Error:(35, 55) error: package com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader does not exist
Error:(36, 55) error: package com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader does not exist
Error:(48, 10) error: cannot find symbol class IDownloaderService
Error:(49, 10) error: cannot find symbol class IStub
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the `aidl` file in the correct place? (this changed when moving to gradle). Side note: make the `appcompat-v7` the same version in all modules as a tidy up

Comment: @Blundell What's this aidl file? I couldn't find any mention of this file in the official documentation, could you please point me to the correct place?

Comment: maybe it's not an `aidl` looking at the demo, even though the logcat hints at it. / Oh wait you know you'll get that error if you run on an emulator or a device without google provisioning? _i think_

Answer (score 0):

The Android Interface Definition Language ([AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)) file might be at the wrong location looking at your error message. You need to browse the [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) to find out what your problem is. While you read that, you will be able to determine whether my wild guess is accurate by checking the differences between the desired setup and your setup. Even if I am not right, even in that case reading the guide will help you start going.